# Javascript: Calculate array ration from a given value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to calculate the resulting ratio value for a given number distributed proportionally on a given array. The array length will be random. eg

```
var arr = [45,23,7]
function array(arr){
    var share = 3250.00
    // logic to share the array 
    return array
}
```

I can't seem to get the distribution right, I know there is neither Math.sum nor Math.ration, what's the best approach to this without running into complex normalizations

Comment: OK. Now what is your question?

Comment: The question is not clear - what's mean array ration? pls clarify what you need to do

Comment: Its usually those with no answers who criticize the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming you're trying to distribute the `share` value proportionally amongst the members of `arr` based on their proportion of the total sum of the array:

```
var arr = [45,23,7];

function ration(arr, share){
    var total = arr.reduce(function(x, y) {
      return x + y;
    });
    return arr.map(function(x) {
      return (x / total) * share;
    });
}

var rationedArr = ration(arr, 3250.00);
```

I've broken the share value out into an argument to make the function more flexible, and renamed the function `ration` because calling it `array` is a bad idea.

Comment: Nice +1. I still find it ridiculous that there isn't a `Math.sum` or equivalent function.